# pagePiling.js pp-scrollable not working for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagepiling.js

there
 I have been using the [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) library for creating a scrollable website, and used the `pp-scrollable` class for allowing scroll for contents that are huge so that the user can `scroll` through the section content before moving on to another section.

The functionality is working fine on desktop browsers but isn't working on mobile browsers.

Has anyone had any similar issues with the plugins, if so please any help or tips is welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: To be solved https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/issues/44

Comment: pp-scrollable section losses its focus .. to use keyboard arrows to scroll first I click on any part of the pp-scrollable section then only I can use arrow keys to scroll .